# How can I prohibit the use of the command on certain roles

Tags: discord.js

I want to write code that will check if the roles are in the list. If yes, then they can be issued, and if not, then no. I'm new in discord js.

```js
    if(!rMember.roles.has((['00000000000000', '00000000000000, '00000000000000', '00000000000000', '00000000000000']))) return message.reply("nope.");

    const Discord = require("discord.js");

    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

      if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return message.reply();
      let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
      if(!rMember) return message.reply("I can't find player.");
      let role = args.join(" ").slice(22);
      if(!role) return message.reply("specify rang!");
      let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, role);
      if(!gRole) return message.reply("I can't find this rang!.");

      if(rMember.roles.has(gRole.id)) return message.reply("I can't do it.");
      if(!rMember.roles.has((['00000000000000', '00000000000000, '00000000000000', '00000000000000', '00000000000000']))) return message.reply("nope.");
      await(rMember.removeRoles(['00000000000000', '00000000000000, '00000000000000', '00000000000000', '00000000000000']));
      await(rMember.addRole(gRole.id));

      try{
        await rMember.send(`Your rang was changed to ${gRole.name}!`)
      }catch(e){
      }
    }

    module.exports.help = {
      name: "role"
    }
```

It works without check code, but if I add it, all times, when I will try to change role of user, it gives out "nope".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check whether the given role is in the list of allowed roles using [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const allowed = ['id', 'anotherID', 'andAnother'];

if (!allowed.includes(gRole.id)) return;
// Returns if the role is *not* in the 'allowed' array.
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn’t explain well.
So, I need to check what role is issued, and not what role has person.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. In your question you say "I want to write code that will check if the roles are in the list," but now you've said "I need to check what role is issued." These are two different things.

Comment: "I want to write code that will check if the roles are in the list. If yes, then they can be issued, and if not, then no" So, I need to check what role is issued.

Comment: Perfect example of an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're trying to accomplish X by doing Y, but asking how to do Y instead of how to solve X. Let's focus on X - checking if the roles are in the list. What roles are you referring to?

Comment: Let's say it will be "moderator"

Comment: Whose roles do you want to check?

Comment: In what sense, whose? I want to check if the giving role is in the allowed list